# Postman en POST no arroja error de sintaxis

Tags: php, postman

Buen dia tengo un problema resulta que estoy haciendo una api rest con pho nativo usando postman me sale todo bien en relación a mis consultas a base de datos, pero por ejemplo
si me sale un error donde yo se que me hace falta un punto y com solo me arroja en blanco el resultado y da error 500, no se como solucionar esa parte alguien tiene una idea de que pueda ser?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], He visto que has agregado Imágenes, es preferible que tus ejemplos sean en texto y facilites el uso del mismo, También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: el error esta en tu codigo de php, no en tu suite de pruebas de postman, por lo que voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque Parece ser un problema que no se puede reproducir

Answer (score 2):

El error deberías poder depurarlo en la consola donde estés corriendo el proyecto, o en los archivos de log, o en su defecto si hay un error devolver este error como respuesta de tu api, sino lo retornas postman no podrá mostrar nada, pero lo mas seguro es que este error se esté mostrando en tu consola de desarrollo o bien en algún archivo de logs (en caso de correrlo con xampp)

Comment: super, muchas gracias, donde localizo el archivo de logs si estoy usando xampp?

Comment: ESto no es una respuesta, bien pudo ser un comentario.